# Samsung Note 2 skips over <input type="date" /> fields

Tags: html, samsung-mobile

I have 3 inputs in a row, 2 text inputs with a date input in between.

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="date" />
<input type="text" />
```

When the user focuses on the first text input, the keyboard on the Samsung Note 2 has a "Next" button. When the user taps "Next" I want the date field to get focus, but instead the second text field gets focus.

How can I get the date field to get focus with the keyboard "Next" button?

JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/yKp9V/

Comment: I have a similar issue. Did you ever get it resolved?

Comment: @ftr unfortunately no :( I think the client just accepted that it would be a non-resolvable issue on that device. I was building a Cordova app when I ran into this issue - if you are too you may be able to fix the issue by leveraging https://crosswalk-project.org/. Good luck!